Run specific code after Blazor authentication
I'm developing a Blazor Server Application (.NET 8) which uses authentication.
I configured the project to use authentication this way in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(policy => policy.FallbackPolicy = policy.DefaultPolicy);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

And marked the pages with the Authorize attribute in _Imports.razor:
@attribute [Authorize]

First time when I started debugging the application redirected to the Microsoft login page automatically and after successfully login I could get the username through the AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync method.
I have points which are unclear:

How can I navigate to the Microsoft login page manually to switch user?

How can I log out the user? When I restart the debugging I'm still logged in.

I need other user data from my database but only if user is logged in. I don't want to get these data every time when user refreshes a page. Can I store these data somewhere and call the data loading when user is logged in and these data are missing?



To signout from entra ID, you need to use "HttpContext" which is only awailable in SSR or MVC or RazorPages. A common solution is redirect to Razor pages then use HttpContext to signout. (The same to login) .
First add Razor Pages support to program.cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...
app.MapRazorPages();

Then create Razor pages Login.cshtml and Logout.cshtml, modify the "code behind file like following:
Login.cshtml.cs
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
        {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new
                AuthenticationProperties
            { RedirectUri = redirectUri });
        }
    }

Logout.cshtml.cs
    public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }

After this you could login via NavigationManager in any component like
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
...
var returnUrl = _navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);                   
_navigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);

To logout
_navigationManager.NavigateTo($"logout"}", forceLoad: true);

Since you have set the fallback("any page without policy") policy to default policy("require authenticated user"), you don't have to put the @attribute [Authorize] in the _import again. Instead, you should put an @attribute [AllowAnonymous] in the page doesn't need login such as "/home". Also, the login pagemode should have this attribute
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
...

To switch user, You could use cookie to store the accounts names. Then when  a user has login, he could choose from the name list to perform logout and login again manually.
Also you could store the user data to cookie after encrypted. So next time you could retrive user data from browser cookie directly instead of from database.

I cannot find HttpContext because it is Blazor. And login is automatically called (the Microsoft login page) when page is marked with the Authorize attribute.

@Panthesilea Above all, you need to redirect to a page where HttpContext is available. Adding Azure login to blazor is not a built-in way (It may redirect you to login page, but you cannot control how to logout). You reference this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853618/oidc-authentication-in-server-side-blazor.
